# Why is the reference to the URLSession configuration object breaking?

Tags: swift

Using Swift 5. Trying to create a `URLSession`, ie.

```
init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration, delegate: URLSessionDelegate?, delegateQueue: OperationQueue?)
```

...but I can only initialize with the configuration object, if I try to add the delegate, the argument for configuration ( a reference to the `default` class variable) breaks and I get the 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context' error.

Providing the code below, which I think is correct...

```
fileprivate lazy var session: URLSession = { return URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil) }()
```

Does someone know why this is happening ?

Comment: That happens if `self` has not been declared to conform to `URLSessionDelegate`.

Comment: By the way, you don't need the closure syntax. `lazy var session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is with your class, or handling object, I tried it and worked just fine:

```
class Trying: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate {

    fileprivate lazy var session: URLSession = { return URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil) }()
    
    override init() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Rob and @AndyNadal. The initial class itself does not conform to `URLSessionDelegate` and I was forgetting that because of this it requires an extension that does.